# How to populate a range of dates in a column using two dateTimePickers?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datetime, datetimepicker

I have to populate a range of dates in a column using SQL Server, WinForms and two DateTimePickers. The first DateTimePicker is start date of the range and second in finish date of the range and there must be inserted all dates in the column, which are included between date chosen in the first DateTimePicker and second DateTimePicker.

I have already tried to implement it using code shown below, but it doesn't work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =.\SQLEXPRESS01; Initial Catalog = Vagtplan; Integrated Security = True"))

        {
            DateTime startDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            DateTime finishDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;
            DateTime finishDate1 = finishDate.AddDays(+1);
            DateTime countDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;

           while (!countDate.ToString().Equals(finishDate1.ToString()));
                {
                    if ((countDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) | (countDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday) 
                        | (countDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday) | (countDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                        | (countDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday) | (countDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) | (countDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
                    {
                        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Vagter] ([Dato]) VALUES ('" + countDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "')", con);
                        con.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    countDate = countDate.AddDays(1.0);
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Vagtplanen er oprettet");

        }



    }
```

The expected result is populating all dates between date chosen in the first DateTimePicker and date chosen in second DateTimePicker, in the column. Right now there happens nothing. Now errors shown, just nothing.

Comment: FYI, In your code, you define `startDate` but never use it.

Comment: Don't convert dates to strings to compare them. `while (!countDate.Equals(finishDate1))` should work just fine.

Comment: You have a semicolon after your `while` statement (at the end of the line that starts with `while`), **which effectively creates an endless loop**. That's why "nothing is happening". Remove that semi colon and try again.

Comment: Why do you have the comparison for each day of the week in your `if` statement? Won't that *always* be true?

Comment: You should consider storing dates as a `DATE` or `DATETIME` in your database rather than converting them to strings.

Comment: You can also gather all the date information first, then execute a single `INSERT` statement to update the database rather than doing db round-trips on each loop.

Comment: Yes, column's [Dato] datatype is DATE....and how to gather all dateinformation first? In a dummy table, or something like DUAL in Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the semi-colon at the end of the line with the while. Just remove it.

Since you have the semi-colon in there, the code inside your brackets will not be executed and the loop will execute repeatedly.

Replace:

```
while (!countDate.ToString().Equals(finishDate1.ToString()));
```

With:

```
while (!countDate.ToString().Equals(finishDate1.ToString()))
```

Comment: This code can and should be improved. Comparing Dates as string, | operator, sql injection, SOLID principles, missing using statements, hard coded connectionstrings, defining unnecessary variables, to name a few.

Comment: In the matter of fact the column [Dato] is defined as datatype DATE in the database and this is also table's [Vagter] primary key....how would you improve this code?